# What to use to take data from server?

Tags: android, sockets, architecture, server

I have an Android application and server.
I need to send the data from server to mobile application every seconds.

What to use to take data from server:

- Sockets
- Simple HTTP request

Answer (score 0):

With no other details, requirements, or constraints, HTTP Request is easier.  It avoids firewall issues, has lots of simple libraries, covers concerns like caching, and your server becomes much simpler to write.